# Java:Unreachable statement error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, unreachable-code

for the following code mentioned below  ,I have been obtaining the  Error " Unreachable statement  error "  at   " Return Cols " statement

The code computes the position of Maximum Dose in a generated  Output  CSV file

```
public int getPosition() {

        double dose = 0.0;
        double position = 0.0;
        int rows = 0;
        int cols = 0;

        String s;

        for (int j = 1; j < nz; j++) {
            s = "";
            for (int i = 1; i < nx; i++) {
                for (DetEl det_el : det_els) {
                    if (det_els.get(j + i * nz).getDose() == getMaxDose()) {
                        i=rows;
                        j=cols;
                    }
                    // comma separated or Semicolon separated mentioned here
                }
                // prints out the stream of  values in Doses table separated by Semicolon
            }
        }
        return rows;
        return cols;//unreachable statement error obtained at this position.
    }
```

Any help  is  greatly  appreciated

Comment: your `return rows` statement returns `rows` and ends the method (going back to the caller, with the provided value). If you want to  return multiple values, you need to return an object, like an `int[]` or even better - a [`Pair`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html)

Comment: what do you think `return rows; return cols;` mean?

Comment: Looks like you also want `rows=i` and `cols=j` rather than `i=rows` and `j=cols`. At the moment, `rows` and `cols` are both zero at the end, because you never write to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already breaked from the code using `return rows;`. This statement returns to the caller. So, a statement after `return rows;` is inaccessible

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this.

```
return rows; // when your program reach to this your program will return
return cols; // then never comes to here
```

If you want to return multiple values from a method, you can use a `Array` or your own `Object`

Eg:

```
public int[] getPosition(){
  int[] arr=new int[2];
  arr[0]=rows;
  arr[1]=cols;
  return arr;       
}
```

You should read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html).

Answer (score 1):

After return the code is not proceeded further thats why it is giving unreachable code error there coz u are returning rows and code exits there and thus return coloumns will not reached

```
public int getPosition() {

        double dose = 0.0;
        double position = 0.0;
        int rows = 0;
        int cols = 0;


        String s;


        for (int j = 1; j < nz; j++) {
            s = "";

            for (int i = 1; i < nx; i++) {

                for (DetEl det_el : det_els) {

                    if (det_els.get(j + i * nz).getDose() == getMaxDose()) {


                        i=rows;
                        j=cols;





                    }
                    // comma separated or Semicolon separated mentioned here
                }

                // prints out the stream of  values in Doses table separated by Semicolon
            }

        }
        return rows;// code ends here itself thats why return cols is unreachable

        return cols;//unreachable statement error obtained at this position.
    }
```